# Расположение картинки

Tags: html, css

Очень тупой вопрос, но не понимаю в чем дело.
Есть картинка расположенная в боди

```
 <div class="back"> <img class="background" src="/img/svg/BG 2021 shape.svg" alt="2021"></div>

.back {
top: 0%;
animation: test 1s  ease-in-out;   
position: absolute;   
top: 15%;    
z-index: -1;
}


.background {
position: fixed;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1440px;
 animation: teste 2s  ease;
 }
```

пытаюсь сделать адаптивную верстку, но как бы не старалась картинка вылазит за края, т.е все блоки не выходит за ширину в 400px, к примеру, а картинка имеет длину 800px

Ошибка, скорее всего, наитупейшая, но в притык ее не вижу(

Comment: Не совсем понял, что должно получиться, но то, что у тебя родительский блок имеет postion: absolute, а дочерний position: fixed уже очень странно) И зачем-то свойство top два раза указано.

Comment: А от чего, по-вашему, картинка берет ширину 100% ?

Comment: @kost1k, случайно оставила top: 0% (

Comment: @Инквизитор по-хорошему должна брать ширину от дива

Answer (score 0):

В общем, глаза замылились и делала всякую ерунду.
Вдруг, если кто тоже столкнется с этой проблемой.
Внимательно посмотри на расположение дива с картинкой относительно других элементов, выставь отступ, если такой требуется от элемента перед этим дивом, а не относительно всего тела. А так же поставь ширину у дива и image, которую вставляешь в блок.
А всем отвечавшим спасибо, что уделили время тупой девочке)

Comment: А можно спросить, зачем такое нагромождение? Почему просто не `background-image`? да и  для `img` свойство `object-fit` тут как раз в тему.